# Examine the uniform continuity $f(x)=\frac{\tan(\sin x)-\frac{(\sin x)^{3}}{6}}{x^{5}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: (0, \frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $f(x)=\frac{\tan(\sin x)-\frac{(\sin x)^{3}}{6}}{x^{5}}$. Examine the uniform continuity in $(0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ and in $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I tried to use one of claims:

- $f'$ limited $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is uniform continuity
- for all $x_{n}, y_{n}$ such that $(x_{n}-y_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ we have $(f(x_{n})-f(y_{n}))\rightarrow 0$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous
- $\forall _{\epsilon>0} \exists_{\delta>0} \forall _{x,y \in A} (|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous.
  However in this task I have trigonometric functions and I have a problem to use some of this claims and I think that I need some clever way to do it.
  Can you get me some tips?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$, so cannot be uniformly continuous on $(0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$. It is continuous on $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$ so uniformly continuous on that interval.

Comment: @YuDing "$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)= \infty$, so cannot be uniformly continuous on $(0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$" because if $f$ is unlimited then also $f'$ is unlimited, yes?

Comment: for any $\delta$, you see $|f(\delta')-f(\delta)|>1$ for $\delta'$ sufficiently close to $0$, so it is not uniformly continuous. I think here one need not think about $f'$, in fact it could be $f'$ not bounded yet $f$ is still uniformly continuous (e.g. $f(x)=x\sin \frac 1x$). $f'$ being bounded is basically saying $f$ is "Lipschitz".